# How to display values of multiple cookies into table rows?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have table with 2 columns user and password, I want to get multiple value of cookies(username and password) display it in each column of table. Here is js functions, the function getCookie2() is to display cookies in table rows:

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    const d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    let expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
  }

  function getCookie(cname) {
    let name =  cname + "=";
    let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    let ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
       var c = ca[i];
       while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
       if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) 
           return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
  }
function checkCookie() {
    let user = getCookie("username");
    let password = getCookie("password");
    if (user != "" && password != "") {
      alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
       user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       password = prompt("Please enter your password:","");
       document.getElementsByName("chktext[1]")[0].value = user;
       document.getElementsByName("chktext2[1]")[0].value = password;
       if ( user != null  && password != null ) {
         setCookie("u", user, 30);
         setCookie("p", password, 30);
       }
    }
  }
var show_cookies = document.getElementById("myRow");
function getCookie2() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    var ret = '';
    for(var i = 1; i <= cookies.length; i++) {
      ret = "<td>" + cookies[i-2] +  "<td>" + cookies[i-1]  ;
    }
    return ret;
  }
```

Here is html table to show username and password from cookies to each row:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>USER</td>
        <td>PASSWORD</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="myRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As I input values like 'A' and 'B' it will display 'username=A' and 'username=B'. How I can make it display only 'A' and 'B'?

I have tried to change to `var cookies = document.cookie.split('=')[0];` in `getCookie2()` but not working.

Answer (score 1):

You already created functions for getting a specific cookie value. Use that to get the username and password.

Do note that you're mixing the name of the cookies, for example, storing the cookie as `u` with `setCookie` and getting the cookie `username` with `getCookie`. Make sure you're either using `u` or `username`.

```
var show_cookies = document.getElementById("myRow");
function getCookie2() {
  var ret = '';
  ret += '<td>' + getCookie('username') + '</td>';
  ret += '<td>' + getCookie('password') + '</td>';
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  You made it simply code and its worked!